# Run java class from single command using makefile

Tags: java, makefile

I have a homework assignment in Java that is tested using the commands:

```
make
./<program_name> <arguments>
```

my make file compiles my java program successfully, but how can the program be run without using the command:

```
java <program_name>
```

I have investigated how to convert a .jar into an .exe but I am convinced that is not the answer I am looking for.

I believe the test is run on a Linux machine. Is there something I can include in the make file to cause the command

```
./<program_name>
```

to run a compiled java class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without converting the java program in a native executable file, that will be different for linux, for windows and any other platform (so you will loose Java portability), the only thing you can do is to create a launch script.

On *nix system you can create a bash script and on windows a batch script. Then in this script you have to call `java <program_name>`.
With the script you are now able to launch your application with a single command.

For example on unix you can create `myapp.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -classpath bin com.test.YourApp $*
```

and make this script runnable with command

```
chmod a+x myapp.sh
```

in this example when you write `myapp.sh` command you launch your Java class `com.test.YourApp` using the folder `bin` as classpath.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize I could submit extra files, but I have just learned that I can so I will use a bash script like you have suggested.